# What does => mean in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm really confused about what this '=>' symbol is doing in a basic node.js tutorial that I just try to learn to.

This is the used of the syntax:

```js
http.createServer((req,res)=>{
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/html'});
  res.end('<h1>Hello NodeJS</h1>');
})
```

I'm a php developer and really want to try Node.js, just stuck and curious about this specific symbol mean and I try to google it but failed.

Comment: They are called `arrow functions`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: [Arrow function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)